# Where to use renv::snapshot() in the document

Tags: renv

I am working on a replication file and am trying to figure out how to properly use "renv". I've read the documentation, but I'm still a bit confused on how to actualize this.
After initializing via

```
renv::init()
```

I know I upload packages and work as normal, does

```
renv::snapshot()
```

then just need to be called at the end of the document?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use renv::snapshot() within a document. When working on a project, you might discover that you have to install new packages from the command line using renv::install().

Then, run your script again, and see if anything breaks, e.g. due to incompatible package versions or compiler errors.

If everything works, you know you have a constellation of packages and versions that work well together. If that's the case, call renv::snapshot() manually to store your current config in the lock file.

If not, use renv::restore() to go back to the previous working configuration, and figure out how to make things work, e.g. by checking different versions of the new package you need.